# Laravel : Force the download of a string without having to create a file

Tags: laravel

I'm generating a CSV, and I want Laravel to force its download, but [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#file-downloads) only mentions I can download files that already exist on the server, and I want to do it without saving the data as a file.

I managed to make this (which works), but I wanted to know if there was another, neater way.

```
    $headers = [
        'Content-type'        => 'text/csv',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="download.csv"',
    ];
    return \Response::make($content, 200, $headers);
```

I also tried with a [SplTempFileObject()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.spltempfileobject.php), but I got the following error : `The file "php://temp" does not exist`

```
    $tmpFile = new \SplTempFileObject();
    $tmpFile->fwrite($content);

    return response()->download($tmpFile);
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Make a [response macro](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#response-macros) for a cleaner content-disposition / laravel approach

Add the following to your `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` boot method

```
\Response::macro('attachment', function ($content) {

    $headers = [
        'Content-type'        => 'text/csv',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="download.csv"',
    ];

    return \Response::make($content, 200, $headers);

});
```

then in your controller or routes you can return the following

```
return response()->attachment($content);
```

Comment: We can dynamically send filename like this: return response()->attachment($csv,  $fileName); and in the function will be like this: \Response::macro('attachment', function ($content, $fileName) {

            $headers = [
                'Content-type'        => 'text/csv',
                'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename='. $fileName,
            ];
        
            return \Response::make($content, 200, $headers);
        
        });

Answer (score 35):

A Laravel 7 approach would be (from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#file-downloads)):

```
$contents = 'Get the contents from somewhere';
$filename = 'test.txt';
return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($contents) {
    echo $contents;
}, $filename);
```

**NOTE:** Headers can be added to `streamDownload()` as a third parameter as an associative array.

Comment: For some reason this does start the download of the file, but downloaded file is always empty (0 bytes). The macro solution (accepted answer) works for me in L8.

Comment: Avram might have done the same mistake I did:
The closure must NOT RETURN the files content it must ECHO it!
(Just as the example shows...)

Answer (score -6):

Try this:

```
// Directory file csv, You can use "public_path()" if the file is in the public folder
$file= public_path(). "/download.csv";
$headers = ['Content-Type: text/csv'];

 //L4
return Response::download($file, 'filename.csv', $headers);
//L5 or Higher
return response()->download($file, 'filename.csv', $headers);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I wanted a way which wouldn't force me to save the file beforehand.