# How to download controller-generated PDF, requested by ajax call in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, download, laravel-8, dompdf

I am having trouble getting a direct download of a PDF file.

Essentially, the user has some inputs and options on the page that they fill out / choose, then this data is sent to the server via an Ajax call. On the server side, a dedicated controller takes this data and uses it to generate a PDF. There is no need to store the PDF on the server or to display it to the user, I would just like the browser to start a download of the PDF.

I use the [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) library to generate the PDF file with Laravel.

Is there a special kind of response I should return from the controller?

```
return response()->json('status' => $status, 'pdf' => $pdf);
```

The above is how I usually respond to Ajax requests, but I am sure there is more to it :)

The $pdf variable gets initialised with `new Dompdf()`, gets modified, and finally `$dompdf->render()` creates the PDF.

Using $pdf->download() as per the dompdf docs doesn't work.

Also, I have no idea how to make JavaScript do the download, once it gets the file in the response. It would be possible to save the file to the server, and then use jQuery's Ajax.done() to redirect to a download URL, but I would prefer not to save the file on the server at all.

Answer (score 0):

I based my solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23797348/12696757) answer for JavaScript/jQuery, and controller response on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61399522/12696757) answer;

I left the jQuery code from first answer virtually identical, and the controller response is very similar too:

```
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();

return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($pdf) {
    echo $pdf;
}, 'filename', ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf']);
```

I only added `['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf']` after desired filename.